# Access a value from ng-change in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drop down and I am trying to access two values whenever the user make the selection. The value in pdfDoc is "{"pdfId":32,"filename":"Test2","link":"\\test.pdf"}". How can I access link and pdfId?

```
$scope.changePdfDoc = function (pdfDoc) {
     console.log(pdfDoc.link + pdfDoc.pdfId);
}

<md-select ng-model="selected.pdfDoc" required ng-change="changePdfDoc(selected.pdfDoc)">
    <md-option ng-repeat="pdfDoc in pdfDocs" value={{pdfDoc}}>{{pdfDoc.filename}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? What should be the result?

Comment: Thanks. Console log should be printing \\test.pdf and 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-value` instead of `value` on the `md-option` directive to assign the full object to your `ng-model` and then just access it.

```
<md-select ng-model="selected.pdfDoc" required ng-change="changePdfDoc(selected.pdfDoc)">
    <md-option ng-repeat="pdfDoc in pdfDocs" ng-value="pdfDoc">{{pdfDoc.filename}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

```
<md-select ng-model="selected.pdfDoc" 
           ng-options="pdfDoc as pdfDoc.filename in pdfDocs"  
           ng-change="changePdfDoc(selected.pdfDoc)">
</md-select>
```